# Google Places API not returning after second request

Tags: java, google-places-api, google-places

I have a few coordinate pairs that I am trying to poll Google Places for information.  The problem is that after the second request (each request is at least 1 second apart from the other), the third request never returns - it just hangs there indefinitely.

Here is the code that I use to call Google Places;

```
Map<Double, Double> coordinates = new HashMap<>();
coordinates.put(40.7549309, -73.9840195);
coordinates.put(48.8616147, 2.3355015);
coordinates.put(36.106965, -112.112997);


for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : coodinates.entrySet()){
    getNearbyPlaces(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), 50);
}
```

There code responsible is here;

```
private static final String API_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/json/key=%s&location=%f,%f&radius=%f";

private final HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

public List<GeoLocation> getNearbyPlaces(final Double lat, final Double lng, final Double radius) {
    try {
        final String uri = String.format(API_URL, getApiKey(), lat, lng, radius);
        return getPlaces(uri, limit);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(String.format("error getting nearby places by lat=%f lng=%f", lat, lng), e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private List<Place> getPlaces(final String uri, final Integer limit) throws IOException {

    Integer maxLimit = Math.min(limit, MAXIMUM_RESULTS); // max of 60 results possible
    int pages = (int) Math.ceil(maxLimit / (double) MAXIMUM_PAGE_RESULTS);

    final List<Place> places = new LinkedList<>();

    String updatedUri = uri;
    // new request for each page
    for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
        final String raw = this.get(updatedUri);
        places.add(new Place(parseRawIntoPlace(raw)));  
        final String nextPage = parseNextPage(raw);
        if (nextPage != null) {
            maxLimit -= MAXIMUM_PAGE_RESULTS;
            updatedUri = getNextUri(nextPage);
            sleep(3000); // Page tokens have a delay before they are available... 3 seconds ought to be plenty ...
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return places;
}


private String get(final String uri) throws IOException {
    try {
        final HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
        return readString(client.execute(get));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
}
```

Of note is that this code worked fine till about a couple of weeks ago.  This is a recent manifestation.

If I kill the application, and run it again, it will complete the two requests, then just hang on the third one, again.

I have tried different coordinates at different order - I still get the same result (I tried to eliminate the very remote possibility of Google not liking a particular coordinate pair)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

FYI - my usage of the Places API falls well within their usage policies, and a fraction of the 2500 per day quota.

Comment: Perhaps you're hitting the default maxConnections limit of 2 in HttpClient.  Check that your `readString` method is calling `close` on the CloseableHttpResponse, or as a quick test see if  `client.setMaxConnPerRoute(3)` makes a difference.  Hard to tell if that's the issue without a more complete example though.